Error: Header name must be a valid HTTP token ["API key"]
Hello postman Help desk.
I am working on the FreshServices APIs, and for that I am testing the APIs with Postman, but I am getting errors as given Below:

As you can go through the APIs documentation of FreshServices and testing with Postman:
https://www.postman.com/galactic-flare-768644/workspace/testing-of-freshservice-api-keys/documentation/23811926-95124e7e-64cd-4544-aaf2-a476eed06661


Headers key must not have any space like you have did API key instead of use api-key
it will work file

In the request's settings, navigate to the "Authorization" tab
From the dropdown menu under the "Type" section within the "Authorization" tab, select "Basic Auth".
Username: Enter the API KEY
Password: Enter the X


more detail in here
How to get API Key in here

